# Blocking method which waits for adding file to directory

Tags: c#, .net, watchservice

I would like to know how to make something which will work like that. Since Java 1.7 I could use `WatchService` but how to do that in C#? I would like to make this method blocking, not a usual event, so it waits forever until new file will come up.

```
while(isANewFileInDirectory(path)){
     doSomeCode();
}
```

EDIT:

```
     FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(".\\Screenshots");
                    watcher.Created += watcher_Created;

   void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fasuigfasuigf423432FSDFSAasuigf");
            sendResponse(e.FullPath);
        }
```

Comment: Check the FileSystemWatcher class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note: It won't monitor subfolder. For starting do not use relative folders. 

The blocking while waiting till a variable is set by the event is clear, isn't it?

Comment: Also you did not forget `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`?

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be blocking? You can use Filewatcher...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: here is an example:

```
namespace FileWatchTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"c:\temp");
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.Created += (obj, arg) => Console.WriteLine("File {0} created", arg.Name);
            watcher.Deleted += (obj, arg) => Console.WriteLine("File {0} deleted", arg.Name);
            watcher.Changed += (obj, arg) => Console.WriteLine("File {0} changed", arg.Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Paste this into a console application and you should see updates (obviously - change the path to the folder you want to watch...)

Comment: Did I do this right. I get no output when the file is copied to that directory. Please look at EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

looking FileSystemWatcher Class.
MSDN has detailed information and sample code. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Did I do this right. I get no output when the file is copied to that directory. Please look at EDIT.

Comment: There is no reaction for @"C:\" also.